# Acessar webservice externos com cakephp

Tags: php, json, web-service, cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou tentando fazer requisições em WebServices externos com o HttpSocket do Cake, na documentação tem esse exemplo

```
$HttpSocket = new HttpSocket();

// string query
$results = $HttpSocket->get('https://www.google.com/search', 'q=cakephp');

// array query
$results = $HttpSocket->get('https://www.google.com/search', array('q' => 
'cakephp'));
```

Mas caso seja necessário uma senha, onde coloco ela?